# Is my floor unit AC actually dead?

Tags: repair, air-conditioning

I recently bought a floor-unit AC (the kind that sits on the floor and has a hose that goes out the window). It worked for one night really well! The air coming out was cold and the hose felt hot to the touch.

I shut it off the next day when I went to work, and when I came back, the AC didn't work. It would blow air, but the air that came out the front was the same temperature as the ambient temperature, and the hose no longer felt hot. I can hear the compressor running but it doesn't seem to actually cool anymore.

I contacted the manufacturer and they said that it was due to the A/C being tilted on its side during transit. They are sending me a new one free of charge and I get to keep the old one! But if it was just tilted, is there any way I can tilt it back? Can I repair it? Should I take it to an A/C Repair shop? It seems like such a waste to just send it off to the recycling or use it as a floor fan.

Comment: Did you check to see if the water tank filled?  The floor units have a bucket inside that collects the condensation, and when it fills, the thing shuts off.

Comment: Thanks! I did, a little bit of water came out but not a ton.

Comment: When you tip an A/C fridge dehumidifier etc. etc. over, it freon drains into places it does not belong.   E.g. Liquid freon in the compressor where it will hydro-lock the compressor to its demise.  You need to wait a day for freon to drain out of the places it does not belong.

Comment: @Harper I've waited two days and it hasn't cleared up... maybe I can tilt it back or something?